# Android app shortcut does not have name and also the app does not appear in multi-task

Tags: android

Problem 1:
I have developed a app which works fine but when it is installed a shortcut gets created by default as in most android devices . The shortcut just has a logo and not the name of the app. Whereas the app does have name/label in menu.

Problem 2:
The app also doesn't shows up in the multi-task(when the box button is pressed --android L), the app quits on pressing the multi task button and when restarted it starts from where it was left. so the activity is not killed but still does not show among the background processes in multi task view.

If there is a need of any code , please ask for it.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1:** 
Did you set the name of the app?

**Problem 2:** 
Don't have a lot to go with so...
What launchMode property are you using in the activity?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i didnt add the Android.manifest file, apparently i had a blank label for my launcher activity. Giving it a value made it work.

```
<activity... android:label=""/>
```